# What countries have the most Stack Overflow users the year 2012?

Tags: discussion, statistics

What countries have the most Stack Overflow users for the year 2012?

Comment: Favor [quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com).  "Rest of the world" is #1, USA #2, India #3.  The effect of the tightened quality filter is pretty noticeable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to know for sure but one way would be from the [results](https://www.surveymonkey.com/sr.aspx?sm=vU4rF_2bPVQaftSo1s69bGGbvMPXp7ktcfSHiDFP_2bM5qw_3d) of the User Survey.

A more accurate way would be looking at the [Alexa stats](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com) but this is representative of just page views.